# Calculating Intraclasscorrelation coefficient - Error

Tags: r

I´m trying to calculate the intraclasscorrelation coefficient as a measure of agreement among raters. I have a dataset with x raters, and their average ratings.

I tried to calculate the ICC with the "irr" library. However, I keep getting error messages. I also seem to have problems with getting data in the right format. I first had two columns (1 with subject, 1 with rating). The package could not seem to handle that. Next, I tried to reshape the dataset from long to wide format. I tried to use spread and cast, however, none of these produces a useable dataset, that does not result in an error.

```
structure(list(subject = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 
64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L), Rating = c(4.38888888888889, 
3.47368421052632, 4.35, 4.42105263157895, 4.5, 3.33333333333333, 
4.73684210526316, 3.25, 4.33333333333333, 4.26315789473684, 3.5, 
4.38888888888889, 2.42857142857143, 3.15, 5.11111111111111, 3.63157894736842, 
3.35, 3.88888888888889, 4.15789473684211, 4, 3.44444444444444, 
3.68421052631579, 3.95, 4.88888888888889, 4.42105263157895, 3.35, 
3.94444444444444, 3.26315789473684, 4.05, 4.16666666666667, 4.42105263157895, 
4.25, 3.94444444444444, 3.21052631578947, 4.2, 5.44444444444444, 
3.78947368421053, 3.1, 5.02631578947368, 4.5, 3.33333333333333, 
4, 4.1, 4.16666666666667, 4.89473684210526, 4.05, 4.33333333333333, 
4.05263157894737, 3.05, 2.77777777777778, 4.47368421052632, 3.85, 
3.77777777777778, 3.31578947368421, 2.95, 3.77777777777778, 3.36842105263158, 
3.85, 4.66666666666667, 4, 4.55, 3.94444444444444, 4.31578947368421, 
4.9, 4.27777777777778, 4.05263157894737, 3.95, 4.33333333333333, 
4, 3.45)), row.names = c(1L, 4L, 7L, 10L, 13L, 16L, 19L, 22L, 
25L, 28L, 31L, 34L, 37L, 40L, 43L, 46L, 49L, 52L, 55L, 58L, 61L, 
64L, 67L, 70L, 73L, 76L, 79L, 82L, 85L, 88L, 91L, 94L, 97L, 100L, 
103L, 106L, 109L, 112L, 115L, 118L, 121L, 124L, 127L, 130L, 133L, 
136L, 139L, 142L, 145L, 148L, 151L, 154L, 157L, 160L, 163L, 166L, 
169L, 172L, 175L, 178L, 181L, 184L, 187L, 190L, 193L, 196L, 199L, 
202L, 205L, 208L), class = "data.frame")


library(tidyr)
library(reshape)
library(irr)
#check data
df7da3
str(df7da3)
#try to reshape data
df7da3_wide <- spread(df7da3, subject, Rating, fill = 0)
df7da3_widec <- cast(df7da3, ~ subject, mean, fill = 0, value = "Rating")

icc(ratings = df7da3_wide, model = "oneway", type = "consistency", unit = "average")
icc(ratings = df7da3_widec, model = "oneway", type = "consistency", unit = "average")
```

Both reshapes work without error. However, for both reshaped datasets, I get Warning messages and no result when trying to calculate the ICC.
1: In qf(1 - alpha/2, ns - 1, ns * (nr - 1)) : NaNs wurden erzeugt
2: In qf(1 - alpha/2, ns * (nr - 1), ns - 1) : NaNs wurden erzeugt (means generated)

Does anyone have any clue?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: For me `icc(ratings = df7da3, model = "oneway", type = "consistency", unit = "average")` works without error on your sample data. Do you still need to reshape ?

Comment: Seems your reshaped data has only one subject and in that case [Intra-class Correlation Coefficient (ICC) for a single subject](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/421707/intra-class-correlation-coefficient-icc-for-a-single-subject) might help.

Comment: @RonakShah That indeed works without error. However, it does not give me the information I need. It analyses the file wrong. It states that I have 70 subjects and 2 raters, while I have 70 raters and 1 subject. That´s what I meant with the program can´t handle the dataset.